# Driving the skype meetings, speaking effectively in skype meetings

Tags: communication, management, meetings, conferences

I am a decent speaker but in a Skype conference call, I often stay quiet.
Also when there are meetings with upper management I remain quiet.

- What are some of the good tips to speak in Skype meetings, drive such meetings without any fear? I always fear I might speak something which is wrong
- How can I speak with upper management, super senior people with ease?

Comment: Do your research, prepare, and believe in your own points. This depends from person to person as everyone has different styles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** Write down and plan what you want to say beforehand!

I used to have similar issues with speaking on a voice-only medium such as Skype or conference calls.

What worked for me was to have a clear idea beforehand as to what I wanted to say, and **write it down**.  If you find a question gets raised during the meeting, then **write it down**.

So why write it down?  Because it gives you a chance to look at the point, then formulate what you want to say or ask.  It's normally being unsure of what you're going to say that causes the hesitation to speak.  Writing it down clarifies it in your mind so you can speak with confidence.

Once you have planned what you want to say, then when there is either a break in the discussion or a relevant point to interject, look at your notes, remember what you planned to say and speak clearly and succinctly.

I've been doing this for the better part of 20 years and I find that am now effective in my communication in Skype meetings.